# my android app is start and stop immediately

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I'm writing an android app but it doesn't work. It opens and stops immediately. I really don't know where the problem is and why it happens.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rec);
        MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,putName());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    }

    public ArrayList<NameList> putName(){
        ArrayList<NameList> chart=new ArrayList<>();
        chart.add(new NameList("second one"));
        chart.add(new NameList("third one"));
        return chart;
    }
}
```

I have a single `SharedPrefences` class:

```
public class MyShared extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("pref", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    public void Shared(int Int,Boolean boolea){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Integer.toString(Int),boolea);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public Boolean getShared(int Int){
        Boolean boo=sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Integer.toString(Int),false);
        return boo;
   }

}
```

And this is my `Namelist`:

```
public class NameList{

    private String name;

    public NameList(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I have a `RecyclerView` and two buttons: one to save a boolean value in my `MyShared` class, the other one is just a button of my recycler. Where is the problem?

Logcat:

`02-06 04:02:49.591: W/System(3573): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.mehrad.first-2/lib/x86
02-06 04:02:49.679: W/art(3573): Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-06 04:02:49.990: D/AndroidRuntime(3573): Shutting down VM
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573): Process: com.example.mehrad.first, PID: 3573
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.content.SharedPreferences.getBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.example.mehrad.first.MyShared.getShared(MyShared.java:20)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.example.mehrad.first.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:38)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.example.mehrad.first.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:19)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6310)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6343)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5289)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5552)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5394)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5390)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2149)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1533)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1496)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:593)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3537)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2979)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:383)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:431)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
02-06 04:02:49.991: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)`

i edited my logcat

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: Post your error log pls.

Comment: show your error log here

Comment: Not possible to answer without logcat. logcat pls..

Comment: See your error log in `Android Monitor`

Comment: You posted the event log from the gradle console, please post your logcat https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: MyShared class how are you using it in your app?  It extends Activity only to create shared preference?

Comment: `MyShared` should not extend `Activity`. Instead, you need to pass it a valid `Context` to call `getSharedPreferences()` on, e.g., in the constructor, like is shown in the accepted answer on the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling getSharedPreferences() before the Activity was created. Do the call inside your onCreate() method.

Something like this:

```
public class MyShared extends Activity {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: no that isn't my problem

Comment: Your logcat said nullpointer when trying to call 'getSharedPreferences()' on a null object. Yes, that WAS your problem. But now that you fixed it, you have other problems.

Comment: i edited my logcat

Comment: That's exactly my point. It's a completely different problem now. You shouldn't edit original post every time one of your problems was solved. Your question is already marked as a duplicate. With your new logcat you should be able to google or search on stackoverflow for solutions.